# Merge function doesn't return merged dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge 2 dataframe with that line`

```
recommendations_df = recommendations_df.merge(anime_df, how = 'left', 
                                            left_on = 'name', 
                                            right_on = 'name')[['episodes', 
                                                                'user_rating',
                                                                'anime_id',
                                                                'genre',
                                                                "Score",
                                                                "name",
                                                                "type",
                                                                "members"]]
```

the key "name" is in both dataframe but when i run code it works but return the initial dataframe (recommandations) without column that i want (episodes ...etc).

recommendations_df looks like

```
    name    Score
0   Shinreigari Ghost Hound 0.946970
2   Wonderful Rush  0.882727
3   Saber Marionette J to X 0.836957
5   Hyouka  0.812808
6   Super Lovers    0.811879
```

and anime_df

```
    anime_id    name    genre   type    episodes    rating  members map_id
0   32281   Kimi no Na wa   Drama, Romance, School, Supernatural    Movie   1   9.37    200630.0    0
1   5114    Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood Action, Adventure, Drama, Fantasy, Magic, Mili...   TV  64  9.26    793665.0    1
2   28977   Gintama Action, Comedy, Historical, Parody, Samurai, S...   TV  51  9.25    114262.0    2
3   9253    Steins Gate Sci-Fi, Thriller    TV  24  9.17    673572.0    3
4   9969    Gintama 039 Action, Comedy, Historical, Parody, Samurai, S...   TV  51  9.16    151266.0    4
```

Comment: There is not a single matching name in the two dataframes. How do you expect them to merge?

Comment: anime_df have 12k + rows, name present in reco df is in anime_df for sure

Comment: Why don't you give us an example that is _supposed to work_?

Comment: Also, there is no `user_rating` column anywhere in any dataframe.

Comment: my bad for user_rating i forgot to drop it, but it doesn't change anything, when i merge both nothing happens, i can paste an exemple where rows match together visually but it change nothing too

Comment: It _does_ change: we cannot execute your example to check whether it works or not.

Comment: I'll put another example

Comment: try something like `merged_df = ...` than replacing the same data frame after replacing, if you are on jupyter notebook and running the cell multiple times would result in replacing the same dataframe.